# Selectively filter debug logs for Moleculer

Tags: moleculer

I have healthcheck actions within my services that are called to determine whether the service is up. Due to the frequent calls from automated systems, there are a lot of noise in the debug logs. Is there a way to filter out the system generated debug logs that is printed on each call?

I added `logging:false` to the `routes` section and that helped to filter out most of the logging in `info` but 2 debug logs still gets generated on each healthcheck call

1. `{"ts":1684139586416,"level":"debug","msg":"  Alias: \u001b[35m   GET\u001b[39m \u001b[36m/api/healthcheck\u001b[39m\u001b[90m => \u001b[39mapi.healthcheck","nodeID":"abc","ns":"","mod":"api","svc":"api"}`
2. `{"ts":1684139586417,"level":"debug","msg":"Call action locally. { action: 'api.healthcheck', requestID: '0e62a5bd-7dfe-41b2-af84-f4186758cc99' }","nodeID":"abc","ns":"","mod":"broker"}`

I tried to put
`{type: "Console", options: {level: {"API": false, "**": "debug"},formatter: "json",}}` in `moleculer.config.ts` and that helped to suppress the first debug log but the call action locally log still gets generated.

Is there a better way to not have those 2 debug logs appear, only and only if they are `healthcheck` related calls? I would still like to maintain the default system logging behaviour for all other api calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second log is a debug message `ServiceBroker` and there is no way to filter it out of the box by the message's text. You can make your own `logger` and add message-filtering logic there.

Or you can add in `level` disabling of all broker's messages `{ BROKER: false }`

You can disable any group of messages grouped by the name set in the initialization instance embedded logger. In your output name, `mod` points to the name of the instance logger as a group of logs.

You can write this name in uppercase in the configuration in the `level` object and set the desired logger level. It supports a mask instead of specifying the service version `V1.TEST`. You can write `*.TEST` to set the logging level for any `TEST` service version.

Comment: Making a custom logger is the way to go, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

Or you can add the healthcheck action to a separated `route` and set `logging: false` in route settings.